# Get first n elements from List

Tags: list, scala, collections, scala-collections

I have a `List`

```
val family=List("1","2","11","12","21","22","31","33","41","44","51","55")
```

i want to take its first n elements but the problem is that `parents` size is not fixed.

```
val familliar=List("1","2","11") //n=3
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `take`

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> list.take(3)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
List(1,2,3).take(100) //List(1,2,3)
```

The signature of take will compare the argument with index, so the incremental index will never more than argument

The signature of take

```
override def take(n: Int): List[A] = {
  val b = new ListBuffer[A]
  var i = 0
  var these = this
  while (!these.isEmpty && i < n) {
    i += 1
    b += these.head
    these = these.tail
  }
  if (these.isEmpty) this
  else b.toList
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`take`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@take(n:Int):List[A]):

```
val familliar = family.take(3)
```